# check if item is part of dict keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following worker dict (2 keys per value):

```
worker = {('admin', 'unknown'): 1, ('worker1', 'Paul'): 1,  ('worker2', 'Francis'): 1}
```

In my code I want to check if a worker function already has an entry:

```
if work['function'] in worker:
    # increment amount
```

Why is this never true? `work['function']` would be `admin` or `worker1` etc.

Is it because I have to specify the second key of the dict in my `if` as well? Because I can't / don't want to do that

How can I get this to be true?

Comment: key should be exactly match `work['function']`... Otherwise, you need to iterate keys: `if any(work['function'] in key for key in worker): ....`

Comment: well that worked, thanks

Comment: There is no "second key", but you are using a tuple as key, so if you are checking with `in`, the whole tuple has to match.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for the `set` data structure.

Comment: @machineyearning Wanna elaborate a bit? Don't really get what you could do with a `set` here.

Comment: @JustSomeDude: note that it works but is way slower than a lookup in a dict (`O(n)` instead of amortized `O(1)`)

Comment: @Sevanteri He could make a `set` of first items from his pair, and then do the lookup in constant time. He doesn't seem interested in the value when he does the lookup, only membership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key of your dictionary is a tuple, like `('admin', 'unknown')`. You can easily test that this will work:

```
if ('admin', 'unknown') in worker:
    print("toto")
```

So if you want to be able to check for the presence of admin only, you have two choices:

- change your data structure (for example for a dict of dicts)
- use a function that will iterate on all items of the dict to do the comparison you want (and suffer from bad performances if the dict is big) [**Edit**: Typically the list comprehension solution proposed by Merlin2011 in his answer]

Example with the dict of dicts that do what you describe:

```
worker = {'admin':{'unknown': 1}, 'worker1':{'Paul': 1},  'worker2':{'Francis': 1}}
if 'admin' in worker:
    print("Here is admin")
```

In your case, you may rather want a simple dict because you will apparently always have only one set of values corresponding to a key, so simply:

```
worker = {'admin': ('unknown', 1), 'worker1': ('Paul', 1), 'worker2': ('Francis', 1) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
[`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)
to easily get the first item of the key tuple.

```
from operator import itemgetter

if work['function'] in map(itemgetter(0), worker):
    # increment amount
```

Comment: You should precise that performances will be very bad for big dicts compared to what you can expect from a lookup in a dict

Comment: @ColinPitrat When using a **modern** language like Python **3** there's not much of an issue as `dict.keys()` returns a _view object_ of the dict's keys, which works pretty fast. And `map` returns a _map object_ instead of a `list` like in Python 2.

Comment: @ColinPitrat But yeah, I agree with your answer. The dict structure is not very optimal.

Comment: `key in dict` will be amortized `O(1)` whereas `key in map(..., dict.keys())` will be `O(n)` so this will be very slow for a big dict compared to what he can expect from his current code (if he expects something)

Comment: In a worst case scenario (searched key is last and Py2), yes, it would be `O(n)`.

Comment: No in average (key is not in the `k` first keys) it will be `O(n)`: if it's randomly placed, then average time is `C*n/2` with C a constant, which is `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

Python does not interpret such a dictionnary as "two keys per value", but as "the keys are tuples". This means `('admin', 'unknown') in worker` will yield `True`, but not `'admin' in worker`.

If you want a dictionnary with more than one key per entry, you will need a different data structure. You can build your own or use some existing ones like [the multi_key_dict package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multi_key_dict).

You could also loop over the keys and search if your string is included in the keys, like this :

```
for k in worker.keys():
   if work['function'] in k:
       return k
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to specify the second part of the key, you can use a list comprehension to find everything that matches the first part of the key. Note that the performance is linear instead of O(1) as you would get from a hash table.

```
worker = {('admin', 'unknown'): 1, ('worker1', 'Paul'): 1,  ('worker2', 'Francis'): 1}

matching_keys = [key for key in worker if key[0] == "admin"]
for key in matching_keys:
    worker[key]+=1

print worker
```